# mod_rewrite and php 404

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I have RewriteRule /somefile.php index.php [L] in my .htaccess
and header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); in my index.php.
But 404 don't work, and I getting blank page. Why?

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); works without htaccess file.

Don't ask me why I doing like this. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in phpinfo I have Server API    CGI/FastCGI.
and I discovered that header("Status: 404 Not Found") working only in IE. In Chrome/Firefox I see only blank page.
some browsers also show custom error messages if they not more than 256 or 512 characters

Answer (score 0):

Probably your php is a fastcgi, then you need to do `header("Status: 404 Not Found")` instead. Or your headers are already sent, in which case you may need to set output buffering for php. And check your logs ;-)

Comment: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); works without htaccess file

Comment: Yes, I don't see why would it have anything to do with rewriting, I take it the same happens when accessing index.php itself.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a browser issue, try to see what exactly the server returns (if you have no better tool you can just connect to the 80's port and type in the http request with headers) and then think of how it may be (mis)interpreted by the browser.